# How to make my RelativeLayout scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I created few CardView for my project and notice it that my page is not scrollable, I've search and found some method like changing the RelativeLayout to `ScrollView` but when i run my apps it crash it got an error on my mainActivity java. So I decided to change it back and put the `ScrollView` on the top of my `LinearLayout` it works but, my last CardView didn't fully show up some the part got hidden behind the bottom navigation. Can someone help me or enlighten me how should i implement the `ScrollView` inside my xml file?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView ...>
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/btm_nav"
            android:orientation="vertical">

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...>

<technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout ...>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView ...>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView ...>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView ...>


        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `RelativeLayout` inside a ScrollView. Furthermore, if your last cards are behind the bottomNavigation add `android:clipToPadding="false"` attribute to ScrollView and add some bottom padding.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) inside it, and make it match parent.

Answer (score 1):

Make RelativeLayout child of ScrollView and RelativeLayout to match_parent. Also set fillviewport = true for ScrollView